# Keep div blocks in center of page when page is resized

Tags: css, resize

I would like to have it so when my page resizes the 'blocks' automatically go under each other so they can fit the page perfectly but then when they drop down the 'main' div they are in resizes as well so there is no left over space on the right side so it still looks nice?

Thanks so much for the help!

### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### CSS

```
body
{
    background-color: #000;
}

.main
{
    width: 90%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.box
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000; 
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: If I understand things right, your `box` elements are 200px wide so you can have one or more per line, the exact number depending on the page width (in response to the browser window size).  Because your set the `main` element to have a relative width of 90%, you can have extra white space on the right if the (90% of page width) is not an exact multiple of (200px+padding+margin).  You can make the `box` with relative to the `main` parent element or try to center each row on the page.  Which do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to archive the "shrink-to-fit" behavior you want with inner floats or `display: inline-block`.

But there is a workaround with a lot of media-queries `@media all and (max-width: xxx)`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/QvAwa/1/

You have to extend the number of media queries if you want to cover higher screen-width.

This works fine with IE9+, FF3.5+, Chrome4+